# Xamarin project unavailable in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have a Xamarin solution I've worked on my Mac for some time, but now with Xamarin integration in Visual Studio I want to work on my Windows machine instead.
I have Xamarin tools installed and integrated in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. 
When I try to load the unavailable project it just tells me to install missing features, which brings up the VS installation application.

[image]

Does anyone know how I bypass this error?
Do I need to create a new project and import the old source files? Because I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Right click -> reload project. What does VS show?

Comment: It works now! I have reloaded it tons of times before but now I reinstalled Xamarin for the 10th time and it works.

Comment: @ViggoLundén post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had to reinstall Xamarin multiple times to get it to work. I installed it through VS and then through Xamarin's own website.

Answer (score 2):

Try to right click and Reload the project from solution explorer.This will help you to get all the files from project.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click install missing feature 
like this image

[image]