# Unable to load Xamarin project due to "Install Missing Features" error in VS2015 after Dotfuscator integration

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, dotfuscator

The problem started immediately after following [these steps](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html#pctoc-setup) to integrate Dotfuscator.  I had no problem with loading the project or running the application before that.

The error I was getting:

[image]

> Install Missing Features 
>  Install Xamarin to build native Android
>   apps in C#.

My setup:

- Windows 10
- VS2015 Update 3

I tried the steps from these Q&A's (as well as other sites):
[“This project requires a Visual Studio update to load” error when creating a Xamarin.Forms Cross-Platform Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604636/this-project-requires-a-visual-studio-update-to-load-error-when-creating-a-xam) 
[Xamarin project unavailable in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922416/xamarin-project-unavailable-in-visual-studio-2015)

Steps taken:

1. Un-install Xamarin completely (Several times)
2. Un-install Visual Studio completely (all versions, every add-on and plug-in)
3. Backing out the Dotfuscator changes

Backing out the Dotfuscator changes made it load again, but that's not an acceptable solution and I couldn't figure out why it keeps asking to re-install Xamarin.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** VS2015 was obfuscating the error message generated by the .csproj file, it wasn't until I installed VS2017 that I saw the actual error and was able to fix it.

Because I wasn't getting anywhere in VS2015, I decided to install VS2017 and try it there.  As soon as the project failed to load, I got the *actual* error message:

> The imported project "E:\workspacePath\Xamarin
>   Apps\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets" was not found. Confirm
>   that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the
>   file exists on disk.

Now that's not at all where the .targets file is, I put it in the solution folder, just like the instructions said to do.
To make it work, I had to change the setting in Step 9 of the "Import the Targets File" section of the instructions from

```
<Import Project="..\..\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets"/>
```

to

```
<Import Project="..\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets"/>
```

Magically it works again with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ‘Uninstall Or Change a Program Window’ {“Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features”}, Find ‘Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Xamarin’ And Repair It.

It Solved My Problem :)