# Project .Android unavailable in Xamarin (VS2015 Community)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a PCL Project in Xamarin (Visual Studio 2015), and when I open it today it shows me the Android project in unavailable state, the truth is not if this happened when installing something or an error of the physical test device, but I have been trying to solve it for days.

[image: Projects]

By right clicking on my android project, I get the option to install missing features

[image: Click]

[image: Click2]

Clicking install opens the VS SETUP with the following default installations

[image: Setup]

But it DOES NOT let me click on the "Update" button since nothing has been selected to install, what components should I install to solve this problem?

Should I follow the steps above to solve and recover my Android project? or should I modify my file with extension .sln?

My android.csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
</PropertyGroup>
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.5\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.5\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.5\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.5\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.444934\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.444934\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.444934\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.444934\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets'))" />
```

As you can see in my section PropertyGroup gives me the following error:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText> This project references NuGet package (s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}. </ ErrorText>
    </ PropertyGroup>
```

and in my ErrorList it shows me the following Warnings

[image: ErrorList]

Is this related to not being able to visualize my Android project? How can I solve this headache? any help for me? Thanks for your comments and help in advance

Comment: Could you maybe try VS2017?

Comment: I can not fix this error in VS2015? or are you just proposing? @Cheesebaron

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

1) Click `Reload Project`.

2) Delete your bin and obj folder, and restart your VS.

3) Try to [repair](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/73f84c40-ffaf-451b-b644-6a5b65aeaa81/how-do-i-repair-vs-2017?forum=vssetup) VS.

4) Maybe it is the [language](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80513/winphone-8-project-unavailable-in-visual-studio-2015) problem.

5) Maybe you need to reinstall [Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41922754/8632294).

6) Download VS 2017.